# Why cannot the subclass's method inherited from baseclass print the value of field of itself?

Tags: java, inheritance

Guys,
My question is very simple. Look at the following code:

```
    public class Test {
            public static void main(String[] args){
            SubTest st = new SubTest();
            st.sayName();
            }
    }

    class BaseTest{
        String name= "BaseTest"; 

        void sayName(){
            System.out.println(getClass());
            System.out.println(this.name);
        }
    }

    class SubTest extends BaseTest{
        String name= "SubTest";


    }
```

Output:

xxx.xxx.SubTest

BaseTest

I know the methods will be inherited or overridden and the fields will be shadowed in the inheritance. So it is supposed that the value of subclass is printed, not that of baseclass. However, there must be something I dropped. Hope someone can tell me.
Thanks.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/685300/is-there-a-way-to-override-class-variables-in-java

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8647248/hidden-fields-though-inheritance

Comment: *I know the methods will be inherited or overridden and the fields will be shadowed in the inheritance* this is called [Field Hiding](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/IandI/hidevariables.html). When you talk about shadowing, you mean a method variable with the same name of the class field e.g. setters.

Answer (score 3):

Instance variables are not subject to polymorphism as methods are.  So, yes, `SubTest` inherits the `sayName()` method from `BaseTest`, but the method still refers to `BaseTest`'s `name` variable.  Note that the `SubTest` class now has *two* `name` instance variables.

To print `"SubTest"`, you could override `sayName()`:

```
@Override
void sayName(){
    System.out.println(getClass());
    System.out.println(this.name);
}
```

Here, `this.name` would refer to `SubTest`'s `name` variable.

Comment: Or even better, initialize `super.name` variable in the constructor of the class, no need to override the method.

Comment: Saying `super.name` will refer to the superclass's `name` variable, to get around the fact that the superclass's `name` variable is hidden.

Answer (score 1):

Your method is defined in the `BaseTest`. It is unaware of who inherits it. it does not know that there is a `SubTest` class. So when you print the value, you print the value of name from the `BaseTest` class.

If you want to print the value of name in `SubTest` then you must override the method in `SubTest`. Since you have not overriden the method, all your calls are automatically to the inherited `sayName()` which, as I said, prints the name from `BaseTest`

Place this code in your `SubTest` class:

```
@Override
void sayName(){
      super.sayName(); // calls sayName() of the super class
      System.out.println(this.name); // prints value of name in the SubTest class
}
```