# Inheritance when an instance variable is redefined in a child class

Tags: java, inheritance

When an instance variable that is present in parent class is also defined in a child class , is it not inheriting the instance variable?

```
class ClassA {
    int a = 20;

    public int getA() {
        return a; 
    }
}

class ClassB extends ClassA {
    int a=30;

    ClassB(int a) {
        this.a = a;
    }
}

class TestInheritance {
    public static void main(String args[]) {
        ClassA instanceA = new ClassB(50);
        System.out.println(instanceA.getA());
    }
}
```

Output:

> 20

Please explain the output of the above program.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Hidden fields though inheritance](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8647248/hidden-fields-though-inheritance)

Answer (score 2):

No.  Instance variables are not overridden in the same way as methods.  In this example, an object whose class is `ClassB` actually has two instance variables called `a` - the one declared in `ClassA` and the one declared in `ClassB`.  Any code written in `ClassA` will access the one declared in `ClassA`, and any code written in `ClassB` will access the one declared in `ClassB`.

Comment: Thanks David. When you say ClassB object has two instance variable does that mean when an object of ClassB is created then it will have all the inheritable instance variable of its parent ClassA and its own instance variable. But the instance variable in ClassA with same name as its instance variables are not accessible through reference of ClassB.

Answer (score 2):

In Java, if a parent class and a child class have a field with the same name, the field doesn't *override* the parent's field.

When the compiler has to decide which field to use - the one declared in the parent or the one in the child - it does so based on the type of the *reference variable* being used. So, if you declared

```
ClassA instanceA;
```

Then whatever you assign to `instanceA`, whether a real `ClassA` or any child - if you write `instanceA.a`, it means "the `a` that was declared in `ClassA`". If you declared:

```
ClassB instanceB;
```

Then whatever you assign to `instanceB` (suppose, `ClassB` also has children), the compiler will treat `instanceB.a` as "the `a` that was declared in `ClassB`".

But the field *is* inherited, even if it is not overridden. That is, if you remove the declaration from `ClassB`, then the compiler takes `instanceB.a` to mean "the field `a` that `ClassB` inherited from `ClassA`".

The term used for a field in a child class that has the same name as a field in a parent class is *[hiding](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-8.html#jls-8.3)* (which is distinct from *shadowing* and *obscuring* - terms that are also used for certain situations in which the same name is used for two different items).